# Unit test cases for Angular factory using jasmine/karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-resource

I have good understanding on Angular however never written any test cases for Angular code therefore have very little understanding on how and what test cases needs to write for factories. I have installed karma/nodejs and able to run basic unit test. Please help to write test case for following.

**Factory using $resource**

```
//create User factory
app.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/users/:id', {id: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}});
    }]);
```

I have following questions on the test cases.

```
1. $resource make server call. Not sure if Karma/jasmin will be able to make server call.
2. I want to write test case in following order
a. Create new user and fetch the _id from response
b. Get list of all users and get the user details for #a _id.
c. Match the details used in #a and details returned by #b
d. Update some details of user using "update" and repeat #b and #c.
e. Delete user and perform step $b to make sure that user object is deleted.
```

Please help.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend did you read these ? then you can come with a minial test case to get started with. Come back when you have a very specific problem. Right now you dont.